# how to disable lotus note shortcut key.in lotus note

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus, lotusscript, lotus-formula

good day, 
Question: anyone know how to disable lotus notes shortcut keys, for example in a view, no copy and paste a data?

Comment: Is it just the disabling of shortcut keys? Or do you want to prevent the user from copying data out of the database?

Comment: Please add some details. Copy and paste are two different usecases, depending of what your intent is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot prevent copying at the view level.  You can prevent copying at the database level by removing the 'Replicate or copy documents' setting in database ACL entries.  Users who do not have this setting enabled will not be able to copy documents.  (*Please note that there is a side-effect to this setting, which is described in this [IBM Technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21164209).  IBM considers this side-effect a feature.  I consider it a bug.*)

You can prevent pasting at the view level by adding code to the view's `QueryPaste` event and having that code set `Continue = False`.

Comment: >You cannot prevent copying at the view level... 
Actually, you can. Field $KeepPrivate set to "1" prevents copying at document level, and view level too.

Comment: Good point.  I did mention the 'Replicate or copy documents' setting in the ACL and when that is unchecked it actually causes all documents created by the user to automatically include the $KeepPrivate item.  I consider that a bug because it prevents people who do have that box checked from copying docs created by people who don't have that box checked, but IBM/Lotus disagrees and considers it a feature.  Anyhow, you're right: you can certainly use $KeepPrivate without using the ACL setting.